# How to reset the image import process

Tags: images, windows-explorer, camera, import

In Windows 7 (and probably also in Vista) there is a function to import images. I have tried that out but the result didn't satisfied me. So I deleted the imported images in the "Pictures" folder and wanted to do the import again.

The problem is now, that as soon as I try to re-import them, Windows 7 is telling me, that there are not files (no new files) to import. It might have saved which images have been imported. I couldn't find any hidden file that might hold the information about the imported images (the only hidden file was the desktop.ini which had no such information).

Does anybody knows how to reset the import? I would like to use it because it can automatically rotate images and rename them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Delete/backup/rename the file:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Photo Acquisition\PreviouslyAcquired.db
```

And you should be able to reimport. I think.

Comment: Keep coming back to this solution, works perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to re-import pictures on Windows 7. Connect your camera then go to My Computer and it will be listed on left under C: - it's a storage device. You can click it to show all files in camera, then copy them. Took me a long time to discover this, Windows help was no help.