# How to reset the image import process (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, camera, import, picture-import-wizard

The question
[How to reset the image import process](https://superuser.com/questions/182238/how-to-reset-the-image-import-process?newreg=29d010421ade45048d000a65870d1f6b)
for Windows 7, advises to delete this file:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Photo Acquisition\PreviouslyAcquired.db
```

The problem is that the file doesn't exist for me in Windows 10.
I can't even find the `Microsoft` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft folder was hidden for me in the `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local` folder, even tough I had "show hidden items" enabled, but I managed to get there by typing `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft` into Windows Explorer.

And the folder `Photo Acquisition` does not exist, instead the file location is at:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Photo Acquisition\PreviouslyAcquired.db
```